# Get next iterator value in Groovy

Tags: loops, groovy

How can I get the next value of iterator while looping through a collection with Groovy 1.7.4

```
values.each {it ->
    println(it)
    println(it.next()) //wrong
}
```

Comment: You can't...  Why would you want to?

Comment: I need to check the next value...

Comment: You'll need to use a regular loop then, rather than an `each`

Comment: But why... each is so much nicer. Here is one trick: http://naleid.com/blog/2010/06/15/groovy-each-iterator-with-peek-ahead-at-next-collection-value/

Comment: Because that's not the way `each` works...  There are things you can do, but none of them are probably as clean as using a loop and going through your list...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So if you want to check the next item in the list (assuming it's a list), you can do:

```
// Given a list:
def values = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]

// Iterate through it, printing out current and next value:
for( i = 0 ; i < values.size() ; i++ ) {
    def curr = values[ i ]
    def next = i < values.size() - 1 ? values[ i + 1 ] : null
    println( "$curr $next" )
}
```

Or, you can use inject to store the previous value, and get:

```
values[ 1..-1 ].inject( values[ 0 ] ) { prev, curr ->
    println "$prev $curr"
    curr
}
```

Or, you can just keep track of the previous element yourself with an each:

```
def prev = null
values.each { curr ->
  if( prev != null ) println "$prev $curr"
  prev = curr
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Another way to get access to the previous element is with [`List.collate`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/List.html#collate%28int,%20int,%20boolean%29).  By setting the step parameter to 1, you can get a "sliding window" view of your collection:

```
def windowSize = 2
def values = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
[null, *values].collate(windowSize, 1, false).each { prev, curr ->
    println "$prev, $curr"
}
```

The list has to be padded with null at the beginning to provide the first element's `prev`.

Answer (score 0):

The question is very old and in the meanwhile there is a much simpler approach, using `eachWithIndex`.

```
def values = [1,2,3,4]
values.eachWithIndex { cur, index ->
    def next = values[index + 1]
    println "$cur $next"
}
```

which prints:

```
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 null
```